# How do you check to see if there is a specific piece of text in a span tag using Rspec/Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm currently using the following piece to code to check if my page has a specific piece of text:

```
it { should have_selector('test_container', text: 'hiya') }
```

All I'm checking is a span on my page:

```
<span id="test_container">hiya</span>
```

How do I do I test for the contents of a specific span tag like this?  I don't want to check the entire page for the text 'hiya' but a specific span tag like the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Capybara gives you two possibilities here, you can either use the find method:

```
find('#text_container').should have_content('hiya')
```

or you can scoping to restrict a block to an html container:

```
within '#text_container' do
  page.should have_content 'hiya'
end
```

Note that although you're saying `page.should` in the block, it is restricted to the scoped element.